# In what situation should ostream_iterator increment be used?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

```
std::istream_iterator<std::string> ist(std::cin);
std::istream_iterator<std::string> eof;
std::vector<std::string> str_vec(ist, eof);
std::ofstream ofs("a");
if (!ofs) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Open file failed.");
}
std::ostream_iterator<std::string> ost(ofs, "\n");
for (size_t index = 0; index != str_vec.size(); ++index) {
    //*ost = str_vec[index];
    *ost++ = str_vec[index];
}
```

I got the same result no matter I use *ost++ or not. I know the meaning of istream_iterator increment. But in what situation should ostream_iterator increment be used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further experimentation might show that you don't even need to dereference the iterator to make it work. :)

```
ost = str_vec[index];
```

All these no-op methods are necessary to give stream iterators a similar interface to other iterators.

Instead of a manual loop, you could rather use the `std::copy` algorithm. (As that's pretty much all an `ostream_iterator` is good for, this sort-of answers your question: you don't need to mess with those iterators in your own code at all!)

```
 std::copy(str_vec.begin(), str_vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ofs, "\n"));
```

Considering how the copy function template is written, it might become clear where the increments and dereferencing is needed:

```
template <class InIter, class OutIter>
void copy(InIter begin, InIter end, OutIter result)
{
    for (InIter it = begin; it != end; ++it)
        *result++ = *it;  // <-- here, result might be almost any kind of iterator
}
```

Comment: I'm more clear about why ostream_iterator should be used now. Thank you for the std::copy example.

Answer (score 2):

The increment operator is very likely a no-op for `ostream_iterator`, but it has to provide the operator to meet the requirements of output iterators. For example, a pointer is a valid output iterator and that must be incremented.

Comment: @Martin: See http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/ostream-iterator.html#idx1067

Comment: @Martin: But the question is about an `ostream_iterator`, which is an output iterator. As such, your example of `ost++;ost++;ost++;ost++` is also undefined behavior.

Comment: @ Fred Larson: Yes got it completely wrong. Got confused with the input iterator beging declared first in the question and not seeing the output iterator.

Comment: @Martin: I know the feeling. Anyway, could you say that it's undefined behavior to do this kind of thing with an output iterator in the abstract (say, in a template where you don't know the specific type) and yet it's well-defined behavior for a given iterator type (like writing to an `ostream_iterator`) without incrementing it?

Comment: @Fred: I am not even convinces yet (as I can figure out the standardese) that it is defined behavior to use the operator* without an intervening operator++. (Though I am not convinced it is bad either). Sorry I can't put myself on either side of the fence.

Comment: @Martin: I find it interesting that the Apache documentation I linked says that certain of the operators are no-ops, while the SGI documentation says, "Note that all of the restrictions of an Output Iterator must be obeyed, including the restrictions on the ordering of operator* and operator++ operations." So perhaps there are differences in the behavior of these operators in the two implementations.

Comment: @Fred: Yes it was the documentation at SGI that I have previously used: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/OutputIterator.html (See Note 3). But I can seem to find or disambiguate the standard enough to say if that is still a requirement or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm shouldn't be incrementing "an ostream iterator". It should be incrementing *an output iterator*. So, always increment your output iterator if you want to output a subsequent element. This way your algorithm will support a `std::ostream_iterator` as well as a `std::vector<T>::iterator` and a `T*` pointer. A `std::ostream_iterator` increment is likely to be a no-op, but it's not necessarily the case with other output iterators.